# How to place a button over a UITableViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

Just as the title suggests i will like to place a button over a UITableViewController in Swift.

Observed behaviour:
UITableViewController will not allow me to place a button over It.

Expected behaviour:
I want to place a button over a UITableViewController at 20 pixel from the bottomAnchor

What I have tried so far:

I have tried using a TableView inside a ViewController. I have also tried using the approach of embedding a UITableViewController inside a UINavigationViewController and programmatically adding the a UIButton to navigation view. The both approaches explained above works perfectly but i want a better approach when you using a UITableViewController. I have create the UI interface and i don't want to abandon it to use a tableView inside a ViewController or the UINavigationViewController approach.

Error code: None

Version currently using: Swift 5.2

Picture of the UI interface:

[image]

Comment: UITableViewController isn't going to work. You need a UIViewController with a UITableView inside of the main view. Once you have that, add your button to the view.

Comment: There should be a better approach when it comes to using UITableView. i know it probably because a UITableviewController does not have a UIView embedded in it by default as compared to that of a UIViewController that is why it doesn't work but i will give it two days and if i don't see any other approach better than that then i will just use that instead